# TypeError this is undefined whyle using primereact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I am trying to use Editor component from PrimeReact in my project

```
import React from 'react';
import Editor from './editor/Editor';

const header = (
    <span className="ql-formats">
        <button className="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
        <button className="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
        <button className="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
    </span>
);

function Admin() {
    return(
        <div className="Admin">
        <header className="App-header">
            <Editor style={{height:'320px'}} value={this.state.text.bind(this)} onTextChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.htmlValue}).bind(this)} />
        </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

but when I run this code I get following Error

> TypeError: this is undefined

Comment: looks like you are using functional component instead of class-based component, in that case, you can not use "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use function component not class component
please read [Function component vs class component](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108)

[Function component vs class component 2](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/react/functional-components-vs-class-components/)

for shortcut solution use useState

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; //import useState
import Editor from './editor/Editor';

const header = (
    <span className="ql-formats">
        <button className="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
        <button className="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
        <button className="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
    </span>
);

function Admin() {
const [text,setText] = useState('') 
    return(
        <div className="Admin">
        <header className="App-header">
            <Editor style={{height:'320px'}} value={text} onTextChange={(e) => setText({text: e.htmlValue}).bind(this)} />
        </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with misunderstanding the documentations

here is how I solved this problem.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Editor from './editor/Editor';

const header = (
    <span className="ql-formats">
        <button className="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
        <button className="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
        <button className="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
    </span>
);
    export class Admin extends Component{
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            text1 : '<div>Hello World!</div><div>PrimeReact <b>Editor</b> Rocks</div><div><br></div>',
            text2 : ''
        };

}
    render(){
        return (
        <div className="Admin">
        <header className="App-header">
            <Editor style={{height:'320px'}} value={this.state.text1} onTextChange={(e) => this.setState({text: e.htmlValue})} />
        </header>
        </div>
    );
    }
    }
```